# Handle large number of query parameters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm new to Spring. My controller needs to handle a considerable number of query params. Here's what my code looks like at the moment:

```
@GET
@Path("myresource")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
public String getResource
(
  @QueryParam("param1") final String param1,
  @QueryParam("param2") final String param2,
  @QueryParam("param3") final String param3,
  @QueryParam("param4") final String param4,
  @QueryParam("param5") final String param5
) throws Exception
{
  /* Handle query params */
}
```

This style of coding looks rather ugly to me. I wonder if there's some better way to handle (relatively) large number of query params, for instance some kind of annotation that would help me store all the query params into a POJO?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spirng, this is JAX-RS. Removed the spring related tags.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for param and use it endpoint. The POJO doesn’t require any additional annotations. It should have a list of fields which match with request parameters that will be bound from the HTTP request, standard getters/setters, and a no-argument constructor.

```
class ParamsModel {
   final String param1;
   final String param2;
   ...
   //getter setter constructor
}

@GET
@Path("myresource")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
public String getResource(ParamsModel model) throws Exception
{
  /* Handle query params */
}
```

Comment: How would mixing JAX-RS with Spring MVC annotations work?

Comment: @M.Deinum I overlook the tags and annotation :(

Comment: @megamonium Did you faced any issue ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks yes, I made a private inner class called SearchParams with constructor, setter and getter methods, but when I made the GET request, Tomcat gave me the following error: "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class org.mypackage.MyController$SearchParams, and Java type class org.mypackage.MyController$SearchParams, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found."

Comment: `private inner class` will not be accessible for construct create a public class

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can replace all your `String` parameters by

```java
@RequestBody SomePOJO requestData
```

and actually send JSON data to your endpoint (containing data corresponding to your POJO). But you should use a `@POST` endpoint instead of `@GET`.

For reference: [Spring’s RequestBody and ResponseBody Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Comment: No you cannot, you should use `@ModelAttribute`. parsing a body of the request is something totally different than using request parameters for binding.

Comment: The question is about (i quote) _"some better way to handle (relatively) large number of query params"_. So moving away from request parameters to actually using an object sent in the request body representing the query seems like a valid suggestion. It may not be the only way and it may not be your favorite one, but saying _"no, you cannot"_ and downvoting the answer is inappropriate IMO.

Comment: Changing to a request body implies that you know that it is valid to change the API, because that is really what you are suggesting. Keeping the params on the client side and use binding thus a model attribute simplifies your java code (which afaict is what the question is about).

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right, they didn't mention they make this API for one single client that's under their control. I kind of assumed that for some reason. Maybe because I'm working with such a case myself for a long time now. So my answer is only valid in this special case and doesn't meet the question very well. I agree.

Comment: He is asking about GET request. Request body is not available for GET method so you will have to change it to e.g. POST. But changing method type changes the meaning of API and is not backward compatible.